# Trying to use match statements in OCaml to write a function that checks if an element is in a list

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I am new to OCaml and struggling to work with matches. I want to write a function that takes a list and a value and then returns true if the value is in that list and false if it is not. Here is my idea but I am struggling to get it to work.

```
    let rec contains xs x =
      match xs with
      | [] -> false
      | z :: zs ->
        match x with
        | z -> true
        | _ -> contains zs x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use an identifier as a pattern, you will bind the value you match on to that identifier. I.e

```
match x with
| z -> true
```

will bind the value of `x` to the name `z`. You will also get a warning about `z` and the `_` branch being unused.

You also don't need a second pattern match since it can be folded into the first:

```
let rec contains xs x =
  match xs with
  | [] -> false
  | z :: _ when z = x -> true
  | _ :: zs -> contains zs x
```

Comment: Thanks! I had only used pattern matching with two cases so I didn't even realize that you could have more than two.